# F-curve connected sound to text

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I was working in my first intro and I wanted to connect audio light to the song and I miss clicked and I probably connected it to my text. anyone know how to disconnect it?

[image]

Here is the screenshot and i tried to delete it but it doesn't work

Comment: ctrl + z? could you upload a screenshot?

Comment: By connect audio are you referring to "bake sound to fcurve" ? If that's the case,  select the fcurve in graph_editor,  or dopesheet and press x (delete)

Comment: I already tried to delete it

Comment: but it doesnt work

Comment: To delete for instance the x location fcurve, click on its name (list on LHS of graph-editor) it will be highlighted (white) and the graph will be highlighted too. This means it is selected.  Then hit the x to delete.

Comment: Also you will need to unlock the fcurves by hitting the padlock next to LocRot (It will open)  Hitting a over the fcurves will select all, shift click to select more.